# Is there a way to make calls from android app and have full control over it?

Tags: java, android, api, voip, skype

Is there any way I can make calls and have full control over them from my android application? I want to make a call and if the person on the other doesn't pick up, rejects the call or the call goes to voicemail, I want to end the call and call someone else.

I have already found out that it's impossible to find out whether someone has answered your outgoing call in android, even with the hidden API. So is there a workaround for this, or is it really impossible?

If it is impossible, I want to do it using a VoiP app (like Skype), but I can't seem to find a VoiP app that has an API that allows me to make, end and get the status of calls. 
It's sufficient if I can only make calls to people who have the VoiP app installed.

Is there anything I can use?

Comment: free or paid services?

Comment: Preferably free, but if it has to be paid, so be it.